# Positive Lookahead and Non-capturing group difference

Tags: ruby, regex

When you want to match either of two patterns but not capture it, you would use a noncapturing group `?:`:

```
/(?:https?|ftp)://(.+)/
```

But what if I want to capture '_1' in the string 'john_1'. It could be '*2' or '*' followed by anything else. First I tried a non-capturing group:

```
'john_1'.gsub(/(?:.+)(_.+)/, "")
=> ""
```

It does not work. I am telling it to not capture one or more characters but to capture _ and all characters after it.

Instead the following works:

```
'john_1'.gsub(/(?=.+)(_.+)/, "")
=> "john"
```

I used a positive lookahead. The definition I found for positive lookahead was as follows:

> q(?=u) matches a q that is
>   followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive
>   lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening
>   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

But that definition doesn't really fit my example. What makes the Positive Lookahead work but not the Non-capturing group work in the example I provide?

Comment: Would not `'john_1'.split('_').first` fit better for this particular case?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Capturing and matching are two different things. `(?:expr)` doesn't capture *expr*, but it's still included in the matched string. Zero-width assertions, e.g. `(?=expr)`, don't capture **or** include *expr* in the matched string.

Perhaps some examples will help illustrate the difference:

```
> "abcdef"[/abc(def)/] # => abcdef
> $1 # => def

> "abcdef"[/abc(?:def)/] # => abcdef
> $1 # => nil

> "abcdef"[/abc(?=def)/] # => abc
> $1 # => nil
```

When you use a non-capturing group in your `String#gsub` call, it's still part of the match, and gets replaced by the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example doesn't work because a non-capturing group is still part of the overall capture, whereas the lookbehind is only used for matching but isn't part of the overall capture.

This is easier to understand if you get the actual match data:

```
# Non-capturing group
/(?:.+)(_.+)/.match 'john_1'
=> #<MatchData "john_1" 1:"_1">

# Positive Lookbehind
/(?=.+)(_.+)/.match 'john_1'
=> #<MatchData "_1" 1:"_1">
```

EDIT: I should also mention that `sub` and `gsub` work on the entire capture, not individual capture groups (although those can be used in the replacement).

```
'john_1'.gsub(/(?:.+)(_.+)/, 'phil\1')
=> "phil_1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a couple of situations.

**The string preceding the underscore must be `"john"` and the underscore is followed by one or more characters**

```
str = "john_1"
```

You have two choices.

*Use a positive lookbehind*

```
str[/(?<=john)_.+/]
  #=> "_1"
```

The positive lookbehind requires that "john" must appear immediately before the underscore, but it is not part of the match that is returned.

*Use a capture group:*

```
str[/john(_.+)/, 1]
  #=> "_1"
```

This regular expression matches `"john_1"`, but `"_.+"` is captured in capture group 1. By examining the doc for the method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) you will see that one form of the method is `str[regexp, capture]`, which returns the contents of the capture group `capture`. Here `capture` equals `1`, meaning the first capture group.

Note that the string following the underscore may contain underscores: `"john_1_a"[/(?<=john)_.+/] #=> "_1_a"`.

If the underscore can be at the end of the string replace `+` with `*` in the above regular expressions (meaning match zero or more characters after the underscore).

**The string preceding the underscore can be anything and and the underscore is followed by one or more characters**

```
str = "john_mary_tom_julie"
```

We may consider two cases.

*The string returned is to begin with the first underscore*

In this case we could write:

```
str[/_.+/]
  #=> "_mary_tom_julie"
```

This works because the regex is by default *greedy*, meaning it will begin at the first underscore encountered.

*The string returned is to begin with the last underscore*

Here we could write:

```
str[/_[^_]+\z/]
  #=> "_julie"
```

This regex matches an underscore followed by one or more characters that are not underscores, followed by the end-of-string anchor (`\z`).

**Aside: the method `String#[]`**

`[]` may seem an odd name for a method but it is a method nevertheless, so it can be invoked in the conventional way:

```
str.[](/john(_.+)/, 1)
  #=> "_1"
```

The expression `str[/john(_.+)/, 1]` is an example (of which there are many in Ruby) of [syntactic sugar](https://medium.com/@Parmaviolet/trick-or-treat-ruby-s-syntactic-sugar-80c9d80a4c4b). When written `str[...]` Ruby converts it to the conventional expression for methods before evaluating it.